# How to use SET operation in CASE clause in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, case

I have the following structure, and I'm doing a `SET` operation in a `CASE` clause but it is producing an error:

> Incorrect syntax near `SET`

Query:

```
DECLARE @tbl_Result TABLE
(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 INT,
    TtlNOfCmpSale4to6 INT,
    TtlNOfCmpSale0to3 INT,
    TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanFirst SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
    TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanSecond SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
    TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanThird SMALLINT DEFAULT 0
);

DECLARE 
    @Declining FLOAT,
    @StableStart SMALLINT,
    @StableEnd SMALLINT,
    @Increasing SMALLINT;

SELECT
    @Declining = 0.90,
    @StableStart = 90,
    @StableEnd = 110,
    @Increasing = 110;

DECLARE @TrendValue FLOAT; 

UPDATE R
SET R.TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanFirst =
    CASE
        WHEN R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 != 0 THEN
            SET @TrendValue = R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6*2/R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12
            (
                CASE 
                    WHEN @TrendValue > @Increasing THEN 0
                    WHEN @TrendValue >  @StableStart 
                        AND @TrendValue <  @StableEND THEN 1
                    WHEN @TrendValue < @Declining THEN 2
                END
            )
    END,
    R.TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanSecond = 
        CASE 
            WHEN R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6!= 0 THEN
                SET @TrendValue = R.TtlNOfCmpSale0to3/R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6
                (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @TrendValue > @Increasing THEN 0
                        WHEN @TrendValue >  @StableStart 
                            AND @TrendValue <  @StableEND THEN 1
                        WHEN @TrendValue < @Declining THEN 2
                    END
                )
        END,
    R.TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanThird = 
        CASE 
            WHEN R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 != 0 THEN
                SET @TrendValue = R.TtlNOfCmpSale0to3/R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12
                (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @TrendValue > @Increasing THEN 0
                        WHEN @TrendValue >  @StableStart 
                            AND @TrendValue <  @StableEND THEN 1
                        WHEN @TrendValue < @Declining THEN 2
                    END
                )
        END
FROM Result R;
```

It would be better if there is another way to store the result of the expression into @TrendValue so that there is no need to calculate that expression each time.

It would also be good to avoid division by zero errors (that's the reason I added the various `R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 != 0` checks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, you seem to be looking for a way to avoid repeating the same calculation over and over again.

You could use `APPLY VALUES` to calculate the required values once, then use the aliased column in the rest of your calculations.

```
DECLARE @Declining FLOAT,
@StableStart SMALLINT,
@StableEnd SMALLINT,
@Increasing SMALLINT

SELECT  @Declining = 0.90,
@StableStart = 90,
@StableEnd = 110,
@Increasing = 110

DECLARE @TrendValue FLOAT; 

UPDATE R
SET
 R.TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanFirst = 
            CASE 
                WHEN R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 != 0 THEN
                  CASE WHEN Trends.TrendFirst > @Increasing THEN 0
                        WHEN Trends.TrendFirst >  @StableStart AND Trends.TrendFirst <  @StableEND THEN 1
                        WHEN Trends.TrendFirst < @Declining THEN 2
                  END
            END,
 R.TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanSecond = 
            CASE 
                WHEN R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6!= 0 THEN
                  CASE WHEN Trends.TrendSecond > @Increasing THEN 0
                        WHEN Trends.TrendSecond >  @StableStart AND Trends.TrendSecond <  @StableEND THEN 1
                        WHEN Trends.TrendSecond < @Declining THEN 2
                  END
            END,

 R.TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanThird = 
            CASE 
                WHEN R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 != 0 THEN
                  CASE WHEN Trends.TrendThird > @Increasing THEN 0
                        WHEN Trends.TrendThird >  @StableStart AND Trends.TrendThird <  @StableEND THEN 1
                        WHEN Trends.TrendThird < @Declining THEN 2
                  END
            END

FROM Result R
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (IIF(R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 <> 0, R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6*2/R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12, 0)
              IIF(R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6 <> 0, R.TtlNOfCmpSale0to3/R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6, 0) 
              IIF(R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 <> 0, R.TtlNOfCmpSale0to3/R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12, 0)
) AS Trends(TrendFirst, TrendSecond, TrendThird);
```

Comment: It seems like in each case when the divisor is zero, the OP is happy to store NULL. With this in mind, you could avoid the extra checks for 0 in your CASEs if you used this trick to avoid division by zero: `A / NULLIF(B, 0)`. It would give you NULL for every attempt to divide by zero and the NULL would fail every condition in the CASE (giving NULL as the result of the CASE, of course). In fact, that would eliminate the need for any explicit checks for zero in your script.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
WITH data AS(
    SELECT TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanFirst, TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanSecond, TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanThird
        , TtlNOfCmpSale0to3, TtlNOfCmpSale4to6, TtlNOfCmpSale7to12
        , TrendValueFirst = IIF(R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 = 0, 0, R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6*2/R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12)
        , TrendValueSecond = IIF(R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6 = 0, 0, R.TtlNOfCmpSale0to3/R.TtlNOfCmpSale4to6)
        , TrendValueThird = IIF(R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 = 0, 0, R.TtlNOfCmpSale0to3/R.TtlNOfCmpSale7to12)
    FROM @tbl_Resul R
)
-- SELECT
UPDATE R SET 
    TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanFirst = CASE 
            WHEN TrendValueFirst > @Increasing THEN 0
            WHEN TrendValueFirst >  @StableStart AND TrendValueFirst <  @StableEND THEN 1
            WHEN TrendValueFirst < @Declining THEN 2
        END
    , TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanSecond = CASE 
            WHEN TrendValueSecond > @Increasing THEN 0
            WHEN TrendValueSecond >  @StableStart AND TrendValueSecond <  @StableEND THEN 1
            WHEN TrendValueSecond < @Declining THEN 2
        END
    , TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanThird = CASE 
            WHEN TrendValueThird > @Increasing THEN 0
            WHEN TrendValueThird >  @StableStart AND TrendValueThird <  @StableEND THEN 1
            WHEN TrendValueThird < @Declining THEN 2
        END
FROM data R;
```

It uses [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) to set TrendValue to 0 when the divider is equal to 0.

The CTE gets all rows from your table and calculate the 3 trend values. You can then SELECT from it or UPDATE the columns from the main table used in the CTE. This works like an UPDATE in a VIEW.

Sample data and output are given below.

**Sample:**

```
DECLARE @tbl_Resul TABLE(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TtlNOfCmpSale7to12 INT,
    TtlNOfCmpSale4to6 INT,
    TtlNOfCmpSale0to3 INT,
    TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanFirst SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
    TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanSecond SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
    TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanThird SMALLINT DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO @tbl_Resul(TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanFirst, TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanSecond, TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanThird, TtlNOfCmpSale0to3, TtlNOfCmpSale4to6, TtlNOfCmpSale7to12) VALUES
    (null, null, null, 9505, 85, 415)
    , (null, null, null, 850, 700, 15)
    , (null, null, null, 650, 20, 4)
    , (null, null, null, 650, 20, 0);

DECLARE @Declining FLOAT = 0.90;
DECLARE @StableStart SMALLINT = 90;
DECLARE @StableEnd SMALLINT = 110;
DECLARE @Increasing SMALLINT = 110;
```

**Output:**

```
RowID   TtlNOfCmpSale7to12  TtlNOfCmpSale4to6   TtlNOfCmpSale0to3   TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanFirst  TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanSecond TtlNOfCmpSaleSpanThird
1       415                 85                  9505                2                       0                       NULL
2       15                  700                 850                 1                       NULL                    NULL
3       4                   20                  650                 NULL                    NULL                    0
4       0                   20                  650                 NULL                    NULL                    NULL
```